# How do I get a PostgreSQL tablespace on a second, installed hard drive?

Tags: sql, postgresql, permissions, psql, tablespace

I have PostgreSQL 9.5 installed on Ubuntu 16.04. Since it is on an SSD, and I don't want to write to it too frequently, I would prefer to keep most of my data on a hard disk (connected via SATA) that I recently installed and partitioned to an Ext4 filesystem. (Postgres is installed on the SSD)

I am trying to create a tablespace on the hard drive with the following ownership and location settings:

```
root@mycomp:/media/me/EXT4_LARGE# ls -la
total 36
drwx------  6 me      root      4096 Nov 30 23:17 .
drwxr-x---+ 5 me      root      4096 Nov 30 23:09 ..
drwx------  2 root     root     16384 Nov 30 21:59 lost+found
drwx------  2 postgres postgres  4096 Nov 30 22:25 pg_data
```

And from the `psql` command line:

```
postgres=# CREATE TABLESPACE hdd_ts LOCATION 
'/media/me/EXT4_LARGE/pg_data';
ERROR:  could not set permissions on 
directory "/media/me/EXT4_LARGE/pg_data": Permission denied
```

I've tried modifying ownership settings in various configurations, but none of them have worked.

How do I go about getting a tablespace on the hard disk?

Comment: Well not sure about Ubuntu because I use windows but postgres need persmision to write on the disk. FYI, I create my tablespace in the SSD because I want my db be faster. Dont know why you want put the tablespace in a slow SATA.

Comment: You need one extra directory node between EXT4_LARGE and pg_data to allow postgres to write to that directory. Here it is `/ssd/db/postgres/` , with owner is postgres.

Comment: As wildplasser said - it is trying to set permission on the pg_data directory. To be able to do this, it requires read/write access to the parent directory of pg_data.

Comment: I made a subfolder called "db" and gave it the same permissions as the parent folder, pg_data (via `chmod 700`, `chown "postgres:postgres"`). I am still having issues with the permissions when I try creating a tablespace in that subfolder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Linux, users need the 'x' permission on the parent directory to be able to enter the directory and access files and directories inside it.

They need also need the 'w' permission to make any changes to entries in that directory.

From your printout:

```
drwx------  6 me      root      4096 Nov 30 23:17 .
```

This tells me that only the user `me` has `x` and `w` permissions on the directory `/media/me/EXT4_LARGE`. So the user `postgres` will not be able to change permissions of `/media/me/EXT4_LARGE/pgdata`, nor even see inside it.

A quick and dirty solution would be:

```
chmod a+rwx /media/me/EXT4_LARGE
```

The drawback of that solution is it would give ALL users read/write access to EXT4_LARGE. A more fine grained approach would be to create a group and assign group permissions.

Also it might be unwise to give postgres access to the whole EXT4_LARGE filesystem, so as per some of the comments, you might want to create another directory level in between, eg:

```
mkdir -p /media/me/EXT4_LARGE/db/pgdata
chown postgres:postgres /media/me/EXT4_LARGE/db
chown postgres:postgres /media/me/EXT4_LARGE/db/pgdata
chmod a+x /media/me/EXT4_LARGE/
```

Note that the `x` permission is needed on all parent directories, so you might have to adjust `/media/me` and `/media`.

Comment: Yes, the directory permissions of EXT4_LARGE were the problem. Adding the x permission worked. Thanks!